# Android ListView in Activity getting Refreshed on Changing Orientation

Tags: android, listview

I have Activity with ListView inside it and in the onCreate method of the Activity I have code for populating the Data of the ListView this Data is a server based and so populating includes calling Network URLs. I have the ArrayAdapter of the ListView in the Same Activity Class.

Now the Issue I'am facing is that, in Rest all scenarios my Activity is behaving in a proper way but when the Orientation [ Portrait to Landscaped or other way round] is taking place the Data is Getting lost and Newer Data calls are Required to Populate the Same Old Data now this is something that is not intended out the code how should I deal with it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Android will stop and restart your activity unless you've told it you will handle orientation changes yourself.  It does this so that you can specify different resources (such as layouts) that are orientation-specific (among other reasons).

You need to add [android:configChanges="orientation"](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) to your activity delcaration in your AndroidManifest.xml, and you need to override [onConfigurationChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)).  I don't believe you need to do anything special inside onConfigurationChanged(), simply implementing it should do the trick.

Comment: I don't think you need to override onConfigurationChanged(). Adding android:configChanges should be enough.

Comment: OMG Thats the Biggest Relief That I can Ever Imagine... You have no idea how did you just Saved My Life... Thanks a tonn For the WonderFul  insight that you just gave to Me..

Comment: Come to think of it, janfsd's probably right...if you're not doing anything useful in onConfigurationChanged, just let the default implementation do that.

Comment: I got error when override onConfigurationChanged(). No need to override and it's work! Thanks!

Comment: This is a lazy fix! As per documentation, "**Note:** Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort." This will work perfectly in this case but when different layout files are needed for the landscape  view (which is most of the time) this will causes problems.

Comment: You realize the original answer was from 5 years ago, at which point it was the recommended way to handle this, right?

Answer (score 13):

For those targeting API 13 or higher, **"screenSize"** should also be used. If that is your case, add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

to your Android manifest.

More information [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config).

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK the whole Activity gets recreated on an orientation change!
The same is true if you switch to anoter app and return back later.
I would suggest to store the data is the SharedPreferences or serialize them into XML and store them.

Another possibility could be to register your own service that stores the data in memory and the activity poluplates the data from the service.

Comment: I think registering the Service is the Best Alternative is that so.

Comment: Where Can I get More Insight into Android Services for Serving my purpose

Answer (score 1):

Why not saving any data into a parceable and if the bundle you get in onCreate contains a saved state of data re-set the list adapter? Here is a nice code sample on this: http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/10/28/writing-parcelable-classes-for-android/

Comment: Seams the sites are vanished. I'll search for another example.

Answer (score 1):

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

this code will work only if we don't have another layout for landscape mode!