# Android class to share data in activities problem

Tags: android, variables

I have the following code with which I would like data to be stored in and returned true or false when needed:

```
public class DataHolder extends Application {
private long NextRestoreTime = 0;

public boolean getNextResotreTime()
{
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= NextRestoreTime) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
public void setRestoreTime(long RestoreTime)
{
    if(NextRestoreTime == 0)
    {
        NextRestoreTime = RestoreTime;
    }
    else
    {
        if(RestoreTime < NextRestoreTime)
        {
            NextRestoreTime = RestoreTime;
        }
    }
}
}
```

How can I access data from other classes?

I now I have to set like this:

`DataHolder dataHolder = ((DataHolder)getApplicationContext());`

But I have no idea how to do this in ListAdapter

`public class CurrentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CurrentlyItem> { ...`

Am I on the right way to do it or is there any better way?

Thanks for help!

---

Just by doing

`DataHolder dataHolder = ((DataHolder)getApplicationContext());`

I get

```
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.TVSpored/com.TVSpored.Currently}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:129)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:453)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at com.TVSpored.Currently.onCreate(Currently.java:47)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-21 14:40:24.361: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(697):     ... 18 more
```

Activity is in Manifest

`<activity android:name=".DataHolder"></activity>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track for this, you just need to put that manifest attribute under the Application tag, instead of an Activity tag (since DataHolder's not actually an Activity), like so:

```
<application android:name=".DataHolder" //...:icon and :label to follow >
```

Comment: Will that work by storing entire ListView for example? I have problems with ListView on rotation...

Comment: No, that's completely unrelated. This is just for storing variables, your ListViews are part of your activity. You need to handle the orientation change to keep the data between them, as the activity is destroyed and recreated when the orientation changes. This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590162/android-listview-in-activity-getting-refreshed-on-changing-orientation/2592289#2592289

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using something like shared preferences for this, as the Android operating system can kill and restart your application at will, so if you just use a static variable it may get reset on you. Look at the [documentation on data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).